# Dynatree .sortChildren

Tags: jquery, dynatree

I have two instances of dynatree objects on a page.  I have the trees populate from various XML data.  There is an onChange event which has the trees change the data they are using.  The last thing I do during the change is sort the data.  When I call the sort function it runs for both of the instances causing the first one to be sorted incorrectly.  My code for the two sorts is:

```
$("#rightList").dynatree("getRoot").sortChildren(compareNodesRight, true);
```

Which uses this function as the comparision.

```
var compareNodesLeft = function(a,b)
{
   //Find the sequence tags for both a and b.
   var aKey = a.data.key;
   var bKey = b.data.key;
   var aValue = $(GLOBAL_LEFT_XML).find("item[id ='" + aKey + "'] data sequence").text();
   var bValue = $(GLOBAL_LEFT_XML).find("item[id ='" + bKey + "'] data sequence").text();
   return aValue > bValue ? 1 : aValue < bValue ? -1 : 0;
}
```

The other function calls the other sort which is

```
$("#rightList").dynatree("getRoot").sortChildren(compareNodesRight, true);
```

It uses a function that is almost identical to the other except it is called

```
var compareNodesRight = function (a, b)
{
console.log("Comparing RIGHT");
//Find the sequence tags for both a and b.
var aKey = a.data.key;
var bKey = b.data.key;
var aValue = $(GLOBAL_RIGHT_XML).find("item[id ='" + aKey + "'] data sequence").text();
var bValue = $(GLOBAL_RIGHT_XML).find("item[id ='" + bKey + "'] data sequence").text();
return aValue > bValue ? 1 : aValue < bValue ? -1 : 0;
};
```

Any insight about the .sortChildren function would be great.

Comment: It actually seems to work just as expected.  It was apparently a caching issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just a caching issue...